# PHP / WordPress Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed

Tags: php, wordpress, implode

I'm using the Advanced Custom Fields Pro plugin and its Flexible Fields

I'm getting the following PHP warning for each layout related to the `implode` I'm using on the `$displayCat` variable:

```
Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /server-path/wp-content/themes/theme-name/page-home.php on line XX
```

I thought it was because `$displayCat` wasn't always an array, so tried to put `$displayCat = array();` but that didn't eliminate the warnings.

Any ideas?

```
if( have_rows('home_content') ):

   // loop through the rows of data
   while ( have_rows('home_content') ) : the_row();

      // 1x1 Nav
      if( get_row_layout() == '1x1_nav' ):

      $img = get_sub_field('img');
      $alt = get_sub_field('alt');
      $url = get_sub_field('url');
      $displayCat = implode('" "', get_sub_field('display_cat'));
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? `get_sub_field('display_cat')` should return a single field...

Comment: By my understanding, `get_sub_field()` cannot return an array... You could only use `while` loops to iterate over the values...

Comment: Should be on Wordpress Developer Stack Exchange, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: @cybermonkey Wordpess Stack Exchange said it was off-topic.

Comment: @RichardBernards In this instance, it is returning a bunch of checkboxes' values in the CMS. It can be between 1 & X number of items.

Comment: @rnevius In the CMS, there are checkboxes of categories. I'm trying to get each of the checked values space separated. It functions as expected (on the front end), but I think if it's only a single value coming back (rather than an array), it's throwing the warnings.

Comment: @Keefer Please link to the question on the WP SE, as your question certainly *isn't* off-topic there.

Comment: @cybermonkey http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/170032/warning-implode-function-implode-invalid-arguments-passed

Comment: @cybermonkey...As this has nothing to do with WordPress specifically, it *doesn't* belong on WPSE. It's a PHP question. Just because `get_sub_field()` is a function from a WordPress plugin function, it doesn't make this question invalid on SO. The error is a PHP error, caused by incorrect use of PHP functions. It has nothing to do with WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_sub_field()` doesn't return an array...it returns a string. Since you're trying to make an array out of individual strings, you should do the following:

```
$displayCat[] = get_sub_field('display_cat');
```

This will append each `'display_cat'` sub-field to the `$displayCat` array.

Then, outside of your `while()` loop, you can `implode(' ', $displayCat);`

Comment: Thought this would work, but didn't try to implement till this AM. I'm getting `PHP Fatal error:  [] operator not supported for string`

Comment: Is `$displayCat` defined somewhere before the `while()` loop?

Comment: No, it's in the individual `if` statements of the `while()`.

Comment: It has to have been initialized somewhere else, since PHP thinks it's a string. You should be able to put an additional `$displayCat = array()` right BEFORE the `while()` loop, to re-initialize it as an array.